# ScrollView fixed height based content

Tags: swiftui, view, scrollview

I'm working with a `ScrollView` to manage the display of a text in my `View`.

1. When the text is very long the `ScrollView` should stretch according to the `Text`. How can I do this?

I tried a few attempts which you can see here in my example.

2. Also I need the `ScrollView` to be **non-scrollable** when the text is not long. How can I solve these two problems?

---

```
struct Test2: View {   
    @State private var contentSize: CGSize = .zero

    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack {
                    ScrollView {
                        Text ("This is a test textThis is a test texThis is a test texThis is a test")
                            .padding()
                            .overlay {
                                GeometryReader { geo in
                                    Color.clear.onAppear {
                                        contentSize = geo.size
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
                .background(.white)
                .frame(maxHeight: contentSize.height)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The ScrollView already seems to resize to fit the text when it appears, but if you need to change the text content after it appears, try adding this in the GeometryReader to update the size when it changes:

   ```
    Color.clear.onChange(of: text) {
        newText in
        contentSize = geo.size
    }
   ```

You would need a variable for the text though.

```
    @State private var text: String = "This is a test textThis is a test texThis is a test texThis is a test"
```

(replace `Text("This is...")` with `Text(text)`)

2. It's probably not the most efficient way, but you can have a variable for `scrollDisabled` that updates when the text changes/appears.

Underneath `contentSize`:

```
@State private var cantScroll: Bool = true
```

Embed ZStack in GeometryReader (`GeometryReader { viewGeo in...`), then
add code to check and compare view sizes whenever `contentSize` updates:

```
if contentSize.height > viewGeo.size.height {
    cantScroll = false
} else {
    cantScroll = true
}
```

And finally, modify ScrollView:

```
.scrollDisabled(cantScroll)
```

Final code:

```
struct Test2: View {
    @State private var contentSize: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var text: String = "This is a test textThis is a test texThis is a test texThis is a test"
    @State private var cantScroll: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { viewGeo in
            ZStack {
                Color.blue
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack {
                    ScrollView {
                        Text(text)
                            .padding()
                            .overlay {
                                GeometryReader { geo in
                                    Color.clear.onAppear {
                                        contentSize = geo.size
                                        if contentSize.height > viewGeo.size.height {
                                            cantScroll = false
                                        } else {
                                            cantScroll = true
                                        }
                                    }
                                    Color.clear.onChange(of: text) {
                                        _ in
                                        contentSize = geo.size
                                        if contentSize.height > viewGeo.size.height {
                                            cantScroll = false
                                        } else {
                                            cantScroll = true
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    .scrollDisabled(cantScroll)
                }
                .background(.white)
                .frame(maxHeight: contentSize.height)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: hi your answer seems to be correct but i have a problem .. when the text is very long the scrollview expands to the full length of the device ... i need to prepare also the safe area bottom and top i would like the scroll stop before the safe area

Comment: maybe for my case I could use `.padding(.vertical, 40)`  in order to obtain a `padding`   both above and below without referring to the `safeArea`

Comment: Yes, adding `padding(.vertical, 40)` to the VStack seems to work. Just make sure to change the height you're comparing `contentSize.height` to (`viewGeo.size.height`) so that it takes the padding into account.

Comment: you might want to add some delay before contentSize/height assignment `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1)`